# Error: Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode' array.map()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, next.js

I'm getting an error while calling the function, this is just for practice so I have kept everything inside App.tsx. my function looks like this.
Coomonly I think `array.map()` can use typescript but It seems different than I thought. The HTMLElement generated with this map was not displayed on the screen.

anyone know how to fix it?

```js
import * as React from 'react';

export default function KeyLists() {
  let keyList = ['a', 'b', 'c']
  return (
    <div>
      {keyList && keyList.forEach((key)=>{
        <li>{key}</li>
      })} // I got an vscode alert.
    </div>
  )
}
```

TypeScript said.

```
Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(1421, 9): The expected type comes from property 'children' which is declared here on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>'
```

My Package.json

```json
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "typecheck": "tsc",
    "lint-fix": "eslint --fix './{lib,src,test}/**/*.{ts,tsx}' && prettier --write './{lib,src,test}/**/*.{ts,tsx}'"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.14.8",
    "@mui/material": "^5.14.8",
    "classnames": "^2.3.1",
    "date-fns": "^2.28.0",
    "gray-matter": "^4.0.3",
    "microcms-js-sdk": "^2.5.0",
    "next": "latest",
    "prettier": "^3.0.3",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "remark": "^14.0.2",
    "remark-html": "^15.0.1",
    "sass": "^1.66.1",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^18.0.3",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.6",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.6.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.6.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.7",
    "eslint": "^8.49.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.14",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: You're not using map...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code snippet has two problems.

1. You definitely must use `.map()` function in code like this. The reason "nothing is displayed on the screen" is that your callback function returns nothing. The correct version looks this way:

```js
{keyList && keyList.map((key) => (
  <li>{key}</li>
))}
```

Notice `{}` are replaced with `()`;

As a side note: Don't forget to add special prop `key` to list items:

```js
{keyList && keyList.map((key) => (
  <li key={key}>{key}</li>
))}
```

2. Typesscript is correct emitting an error in your code as `.forEach()` function returns `void`. But `React.ReactNode` type is declared in such a way that it accepts `null` or `undefined`, but not `void`.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks, I solved it by your code.